# Is the empty set a dominating set?

Tags: graphs

Is the empty set a *dominating set*?

I don't think it is, because in an empty set there are no vertices to dominate.

Is my reasoning correct?

Comment: Your question already includes a complete answer to the original problem but no question *about* this answer. Thus, only "yes/no" answers may remain, helping neither you nor future visitors. Please read related meta discussions [here](http://meta.cs.stackexchange.com/questions/597/) and [here](http://meta.cs.stackexchange.com/questions/519/) and adjust your question accordingly, e.g. by formulating a specific question about a single element of your answer you are uncertain about. If you just want general feedback, you are welcome to visit us in [chat].

Answer (score 1):

You are right in case that V is not empty.
In case that V is empty the empty set is a Dominating set by definition.